# Error When Building in Android Studio

Tags: android

When Attempting to build my application i have this error on the "gradle Messages"

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Boudz Bazz\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue.
I don't have a solution. But I have figure out something. If you switch to packages view , can you see com.android.support. appcompat ? If not then this the issue. You confirm this by creating a sample app. If you compares packages view for both the projects you will find that you project doesn't have appcompat , in the way it is shown in sample project.